# out of memory error when loading images to a scrolling activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have 90 images that I want to display on a scrolling activity , the first 20 images appear with no problem , but when I scroll donw the app shuts down immediatly
so I want to display only the first 20 Objects , then when the user scrolls down I destroy the first row and create a new row and so on , so the machine won't have to load all the 90 Objects at once

here's my code :

```
ArrayList<Hero> heroes;
SearchView searchView;
GridAdapter gridAdapter;
String[] names = {"Akai","(and 90 more Strings)" };

Integer[] images = {R.drawable.akai , (and 90 more Images) };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_heroes);
    CreateList();
    GridView gridView = findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(this, heroes);
    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
    gridView.setNumColumns(4);
    searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            gridAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent toAtt = new Intent(getApplication(),HeroAttributes.class);
            toAtt.putExtra("item",heroes.get(position).getButton());
            startActivity(toAtt);
        }
    });
}
public void CreateList() {
    heroes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0 ; i<names.length ; i++) {
        Hero hero = new Hero(images[i] , names[i]);
        heroes.add(hero);
    }
}
```

My GridAdapter code :

```
    public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private Context myLayout;
    private ArrayList<Hero> heroes;
    private ArrayList<Hero> filterHeroes;
    MyFilter filter;

    public GridAdapter(Context context , ArrayList<Hero> heroes ) {
        this.myLayout = context;
        this.heroes = heroes;
        this.filterHeroes = heroes;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null) {
            filter = new MyFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return heroes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return heroes.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup 
                         parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(myLayout);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_items , parent , 
                                           false);
        }
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        textView.setText(heroes.get(position).getTextView());
        imageView.setImageResource(heroes.get(position).getButton());
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent toAtt = new Intent(Heroes.this,HeroAttributes.class);
                toAtt.putExtra("item",heroes.get(position));
                startActivity(toAtt);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    class MyFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                ArrayList<Hero> heroes2 = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i=0 ; i<filterHeroes.size() ; i++){

    if(filterHeroes.get(i).getTextView().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)){
                        heroes2.add(filterHeroes.get(i));
                    }
                }
                results.count = heroes2.size();
                results.values = heroes2;
            }
            else {
                results.count = filterHeroes.size();
                results.values = filterHeroes;
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults 
                                        results) {
            heroes = (ArrayList<Hero>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code of `GridAdapter`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of your images has large resolution. Use Picasso or Glide to help this problem instead using the image directly, they are great at scaling image and resizing image.

Picasso : https://square.github.io/picasso/

Glide : https://github.com/bumptech/glide

the example of Picasso is

```
Picasso.get().load(heroes.get(position).getButton()).into(imageView);
```

the example of Glide is

```
Glide.with(context).load(heroes.get(position).getButton()).into(imageView);
```

instead directly `imageView.setImageResource(heroes.get(position).getButton());`

Hope it helps!